# magento does not change the breadcrumbs or category title after changing subcategories from shop by left panel

Tags: php, magento, breadcrumbs

when i click on subcategories from shop by sidebar at left panel
in magento front end, the magento does not change the breadcrumbs or category title,
Like when i select subcategory from top menu magento changes breadcrumb as well as category title.

> So what is the solution to load the appropriate breadcrumb and related
>   category title  when i select subcategories present on shop by
>   sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are on the same category albeit 'filtered' by the options in the side menu.

You may want to roll your own sub category menu for the left hand navigation, also, depending on your theme, see what the different 'is anchor' modes do for your category page.

Alternatively use a wildly-popular extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-4554.html

Comment: thank you for reply. First i click furniture category from top menu then i select bedrooms category from shop by left bar, after selecting that bedroom category breadcrumbs or category title remains same. But it loads different products. Is Anchor option is 'yes' for all categories to display in shop by left bar or to allow layered navigation

Comment: Would you be able to put a tick in the box to mark the question as closed?